# Program for delegates (write program to count by twos and threes using delegates) not working

Tags: delegates

So, this program isn't printing anything and I think it's because I need to put `console.writeline()` but I don't know where to put it or what to put in the `()`. Here is the program so far:

```
Module Module1
Public Delegate Sub MyDelegate()
Sub Main()
    Dim Fns As MyDelegate
    Fns = New MyDelegate(AddressOf FnsTwos)
    Fns()
    Fns = New MyDelegate(AddressOf FnsThrees)
    Fns()
End Sub
Sub FnsTwos()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = x + 2
    Do While 0 < x < 100
    Loop
    Stop
End Sub
Sub FnsThrees()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = x + 3
    Do While 0 < x < 100
    Loop
    Stop
End Sub
End Module
```